# Localstorage not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt

i am using Nuxt.js for SSR. I have a login system whenever i Log in my App, i get an JSON web token (JWT) and store it in my Localstorage.

The problem is now the SSR. Whenever i try to access the Localstorage it says its not defined. I found an Stackoverflow article about this problem, its because the Code is server side rendered so it has no access to the Localstorage.

I tried the `created()` lifecycle hook to check if token exist in localstorage, no success. 
I also tried with `nuxtServerInit` also no success.

How can i check if token exist in localstorage on the client side or is there any better idea?

Comment: To check if the localstorage really exist. Press f12 and go to application tab and you will see there the Local Storage. It will show you the site,key and value. Btw, how did you use local storage?

Comment: Server side code can't see Javascript localstorage directly, you will need the client to send this somehow,  either cookie / ajax / websocket etc, or even a form post.

Comment: @RenatoManalili thats not the problem, whenever i login, i retrieve a jwt from the backend and save it in my localstorage. and i know how to check if it exist, the problem is that nuxtjs is serverside rendered so it has no access to localstorage. i wanna check if the token exist on pageload

Comment: @ilijanovic oh I see, much better if you will use vuex.

Comment: @RenatoManalili i use vuex, after every refresh the storage is refreshed so i need to login again after every page refresh. right now i am using vuex and want to improve the app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may call a function on `mounted`

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.storage();
  },
  methods:{
    storage(){
       localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    }
  }
}
```

OR use `created` alongwith `process.browser` check

```
export default {
  created() {
    this.storage();
  },
  methods:{
    storage(){
      if (process.browser){
          localStorage.getItem("authToken");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is retrieving the data from the storage. it cant because nuxt is rendered on server side

Comment: perfect. `process.browser` works exactly how i want it, thank you